# How to create the knative serving

Tags: go, kubernetes, knative, knative-serving

I have written a custom resource as part of the deployment. As part of this in the reconcileKind function, I have written the logic to create pod as shown below using the Kubernetes APIs in Go itself.

[image]

I would like to convert this to knative serving (instead of creating the POD which will be always running) so that I can make of KPA feature. I am aware of creating knative serving using the .yaml way. But I would like to create it by using the Kubernetes API itself. I did search in the official documentation, but everything explained was using the .yaml way.

So I'm curious whether can we achieve knative serving by directly using Kubernetes APIs?

Comment: What's the meaning of KPA feature?

Comment: Its Knative Pod Autoscaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create the knative serving using golang?

You need to use the Go-client for Knative Serving, e.g. the client type - corresponding to the `corev1.Pod` that you used in your code.

The Go client for [Knative v1.Serving](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/master/pkg/client/clientset/versioned/clientset.go) is in the Knative repository.

Instead of `CoreV1()` in your code, you can use `ServingV1()` from the Knative Go client.

But I would recommend to use Yaml manifests unless you have custom needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. if i use the yaml manifest, how can i execute that yaml file in the reconcileKind so that it will execute. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Also with Go client which is the function? i quite didn't get it.

Comment: ooh got it. Thanks. Can you please explain me wrt the yaml manifest way

Comment: A hello-world using Yaml is here: https://knative.dev/docs/serving/samples/hello-world/helloworld-go/#recreating-the-sample-code

Comment: i mean still we need to execute yaml separately right? this won't be the if i write using api.. when i execute the main application all the logic under ReconcileKind will execute and create..

Comment: @coders yes, if you are writing a custom controller, you should use the Go client, that is a valid use case.

Comment: I will try this out. I mean no change in the code, instead of KubeClientSet.CoreV1(), use KubeClientSet.ServingV1() right?

Comment: you need to import the library, it is another clientset (see my link) and use `ServingV1()` and its types instead of Pods.

Comment: yes, before doing this i need to define yaml manifest using serving API https://knative.dev/docs/reference/api/serving-api/#serving.knative.dev/v1.Service